# I can't see the layout design Render Problem Android Studio

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:934)   android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:954) android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1008) android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1127)    android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1130)    android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1130)    android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1130)    android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505) 
Copy stack to clipboard   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
```

I tried to do Rebuild, and clean the project

Comment: Please provide some code you worked on before this problem occurred.

Comment: 1. Check .xml layout files and resources.
2. Try to refresh the layout editor.
3. Invalidate Caches.